# Animate change in size of div when content changes

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

First: I know that there are a lot of different questions similar to this one. I've looked at a lot of them and tried a lot of things.

Here's what I'm trying to do: Using JavaScript, I'm changing the content of a div on my page. When it changes, the size changes instantly. I'd like the change to be animated.

It seems the general consensus is that 'auto' can't be animated, so here's what I have so far:

```js
    function rightClick() {
 fgContent = document.querySelector('#fgContent');
 rtButton = document.querySelector('#rightButton');
 fgDiv = document.querySelector('#fgDiv');
 spacing = fgDiv.clientHeight - fgContent.clientHeight;
    if (rtButton.textContent === "What's a Grimmage?") {
        nextButton = "How's it work?";
        nextDiv = document.querySelector('#whatIsIt');
    }
    // I removed a handful of similar if statements.
    fgDiv.maxHeight = fgDiv.clientHeight;
    fgDiv.minHeight = fgDiv.clientHeight;
    fgContent.innerHTML = nextDiv.innerHTML;
    fgDiv.maxHeight = nextDiv.clientHeight + spacing;
    console.log('Max height')
    fgContent.minHeight = 0;
    rtButton.textContent = nextButton;
};
```

```css
    .foreground {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 33%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    padding: 10px;
    color: black;
    background: whitesmoke;
    height: auto;
    opacity: .85;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-transition: height 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s ease;
    -o-transition: height 1s ease;
    transition: height 1s ease;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="foreground" id="fgDiv">
    <div id="fgContent">
 <h1 id="foregroundTitle" class="headline">Make a Grimmage!</h1>
 <p class="text">Balh.</p>
 </div>
 <p><div class="btn-group" style="position: relative; margin: auto;"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Login / Sign up</a><button id="rightButton" onclick="rightClick()" class="btn btn-info">What's a Grimmage?</button></div> 
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden" id="whatIsIt">
 <h1 class="headline">What is a Grimmage?</h1>
 <p class="text">More blah.</p>
 <p class="text">So much blah.</p>
    </div>
```

I think that's all the moving parts. I'm guessing that it's more a question of me having overlooked something, but for the life of me, I don't see it.

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS `transitions` (as you have done) and  JS `.scrollHeight`.

Longer explanation:

- Set the dimensions on page load, because Transitions can't animate something from `auto` to a `px` value.
- Set the `scrollHeight` dimensions using the element you're going to replace it with. (Note: For accurate dimensions, the element must have `overflow: hidden` to account for margin and **no** padding.

Finally, to hide the elements, you could put inside the wrapper and hide it with a parent.

```js
const fgDiv = document.querySelector('#fgDiv');
const fgContent = document.querySelector('#fgContent');
const rtButton = document.querySelector('#rightButton');

updateDimesions(fgContent, fgContent); // First update of the dimensions

function rightClick() {
  if (rtButton.textContent === "What's a Grimmage?") {
    nextButton = "How's it work?";
    nextDiv = document.querySelector('#whatIsIt');
  }
  // I removed a handful of similar if statements.
  fgContent.innerHTML = nextDiv.innerHTML;
  rtButton.textContent = nextButton;

  updateDimesions(fgContent, nextDiv); // Second update of the dimensions
};

function updateDimesions(el, replace) {
  el.style.width = replace.scrollWidth + 'px';
  el.style.height = replace.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

```css
.foreground {
  width: 33%;
  background: whitesmoke;
}

.foreground-inner {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Hide the content initially */
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.hidden {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hidden > div {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* This accounts for margin in ".scrollHeight" */
  padding: 0;
  /* Padding messes with .scrollHeight */
}
```

```html
<div class="foreground" id="fgDiv">
  <div id="fgContent" class="foreground-inner">
    <h1 id="foregroundTitle" class="headline">Make a Grimmage!</h1>
    <p class="text">Balh.</p>
    <p class="text">More blah.</p>
    <p class="text">So much blah.</p>
    <p class="text">More blah.</p>
    <p class="text">So much blah.</p>
    <p class="text">More blah.</p>
    <p class="text">So much blah.</p>
  </div>
  <p>
    <div class="btn-group" style="position: relative; margin: auto;"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Login / Sign up</a><button id="rightButton" onclick="rightClick()" class="btn btn-info">What's a Grimmage?</button></div>
  </p>
  <div class="hidden">
    <div id="whatIsIt">
      <h1 class="headline">What is a Grimmage?</h1>
      <p class="text">More blah.</p>
      <p class="text">So much blah.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much! It's already much better, but it only animates when getting larger. When the content is smaller, it simply remains large. (Also, weirdly, the 'var' bit didn't work. It kept throwing an error in the console to the extent that it couldn't read the height of 'null'.)

Comment: @toby.in.dresden Gotcha. Updated.

Comment: I tried to copy this as slavishly as I could, but it seems that the replacement Divs have a height of 0. The div animates down to just the row of buttons.

Comment: @toby.in.dresden Your hidden divs can have `display: none`, otherwise, JS will think it has `height: 0`. In my solution, I hid them by wrapping the content with a div that has `height: 0; overflow: hidden;`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the new(ish) [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) I managed to create this function that will allow any additions/deletions to the input node's children to be animated in both width and height.

```
export const animateLayoutChanges = (e: HTMLElement) => {
    const { width, height } = e.getBoundingClientRect();
    e.style.setProperty('width', `${width}px`);
    e.style.setProperty('height', `${height}px`);
    console.log(width, height);

    const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
        const { width, height } = e.getBoundingClientRect();
        e.style.removeProperty('width');
        e.style.removeProperty('height');

        const ro1 = new ResizeObserver((_, o1) => {
            o1.disconnect();
            const { width: newWidth, height: newHeight } = e.getBoundingClientRect();
            e.style.setProperty('width', `${width}px`);
            e.style.setProperty('height', `${height}px`);

            const ro2 = new ResizeObserver((_, o2) => {
                o2.disconnect();
                e.style.setProperty('width', `${newWidth}px`);
                e.style.setProperty('height', `${newHeight}px`);
            });
            ro2.observe(e);
        });
        ro1.observe(e);
    });
    observer.observe(e, { childList: true });
};
```

All you have to do is to call the function with the parent container as the argument. If you also want to watch for changes deeper in parent tree then you can set `subtree: true` in the options for the `MutationObserver.observe` call. Then by setting `transition-property` to `width, height` or `all` the size of the element will be animated.